# How do I make my iTunes library read-only?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, music

I have a huge iTunes collection and have been researching this for a while but cannot seem to find an answer.

Basically I would like to leave my iTunes collection open so that people can select their own songs. My only concern is that they might accidentally delete or change info in the tracks.

Is there any way that I could have a read-only (or play-only) toggle for my iTunes library on OS X?